# view pager life cycle

Tags: android, kotlin

I have view pager in the main activity, and loading another view pager with two fragments .but that fragment getting loaded while the acrtivty getting loaded.It should called when the user taps on it.

```
class HomeActivity : BaseActivity(), DialogUtils.DialogManager {
    companion object {
        var currentFragmentPosition: Int = 0
    }


    private var isFromSearchHistory: Boolean = false
    private var isFromVisitHistory: Boolean = false
    lateinit var binding: ActivityHomeBinding
    val homeFragment = HomeFragment.newInstance()
    val bookingFragment = BookingFragment.newInstance()
    val searchHistoryFragment = SearchHistoryFragment.newInstance()
//    val tripFragment = TripFragment.newInstance()
    val visitedStationsFragment = VisitedStationFragment.newInstance()

class VisitedStationFragment : BaseFragment() {
    lateinit var binding: FragmentVisitedStationsBinding
    var tabLayout: TabLayout? = null
    var viewPager: ViewPager? = null


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding = FragmentVisitedStationsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }
```

Comment: You really need to edit your question for clarity. It's really unclear what your issue is or what you're asking.

Comment: Apologies for any inconvenience. I have a ViewPager set up for bottom navigation. After logging in, the home menu opens, containing four fragments as part of the bottom navigation menu. Among these, the third fragment contains a ViewPager and two additional fragments. Upon loading the home screen, the third fragment with the ViewPager and two fragments also loads, triggering onResume. I don't want onResume to be called during the initial loading of the bottom navigation. Instead, I want it to be triggered only when the user taps on it.